# Compounding probability (independent and non independent) for winning team

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

right now I'm trying to understand and solve this question for the practice purpose to learn the compounding probability and I'm kinda stuck to solve these 2 questions. Any advice and way to solve it is really welcome

1. You would like to bet on who will win upcoming football match between 2 teams. You have 3 experts giving their prediction on who will win the match. Each expert has probability 0.6 that he will be right. You will decide who to bet on based on poll from the experts (you will bet on team whom 2 or 3 experts say will win). **Under assumptions that the experts’ opinions are independent** what is the probability that you will win your bet
2. You would like to bet on who will win upcoming football match between 2 teams. You have 3 experts giving their prediction on who will win the match. Each expert has probability 0.6 that he will be right. You will decide who to bet on based on poll from the experts (you will bet on team whom 2 or 3 experts say will win). **Under assumptions that the experts’ opinions are not independent what is the probability that you will win your bet**

Edit:
(For the first question) I have tried to separate the calculation to find the probability of 2 experts say win + (because the or statement) the probability of 3 experts say win but I'm stuck how to calculate the probability of 2 experts and 3 experts say win. Is that I need to use some sort of combination technique?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: (For the first question) I have tried to separate the calculation to find the probability of 2 experts say win plus (because the or statement) the probability of 3 experts say win but I'm stuck how to calculate the probability of 2 experts and 3 experts say win. Is that I need to use some sort of combination technique?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the probability that all $3$ experts are right is $.6^3=.216$.  The probability that exactly $2$ are right is $3\cdot.4\cdot.6^2=.432$, because there are $3$ ways to pick the expert who is wrong.  The probability of success is $.216+.432=.648$

It's not possible to answer the second question without more information.  For example, if all three experts always say the say thing, then the probability of success is $.6$, but if they don't always say the same thing, then it's something else, but we don't know what it is unless we know how the opinions depend on one another.

Comment: So the probability for one of the winning team (0.5) is not considered at all for the first questions? I thought that we need to incorporate the probability of winning team 0.5 somewhere in our calculation

Comment: No, all that matter is whether the experts are right or wrong.  Also, there's no reason to believe that each team has a probability of winning of $50\%$.  If that were true, how could an expert be right $60\%$ of the time?

Comment: Thanks, Saul. Right now I get a clarification that the probability of winning team is no more than useful because we are dependent on the experts' opinion. For the second problem is not possible with the given information to decide its probability right? Unless they give how it's the relationship between each experts' opinion

Comment: Yes, that's right.   I just edited my second example, to give the correct calculation of the probability.

Comment: Thanks saul, I’m trying to understand the second example but I guess it’s just depends again on the given information. But your explanation I can understand it

Comment: @RizFaj3105 On second thought, I don't think it's right.  Let me try again.

Comment: Which one is incorrect? The first problem or second one? Is the questions clear or there is some missing information aside from the second part?

Comment: The first one is right.  In the second one, I compute the probability incorrectly.  It also should have $60\%$.